# Как сделать так, чтобы бот работал постоянно?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Что нужно сделать, чтобы бот работал на постоянке, даже если я выключал бы свой пк/посоветуйте какие нибудь сервисы,если такие знаете.

Comment: Yandex.Cloud, Sbercloud?

Comment: Запускать на компьютере, который не выключается (например, на сервере)

Comment: а на каком сервере?(если знаете)

Comment: На любом какой вам понравится, хостингов слишком много, чтобы советовать какой-то конкретный

Comment: Бесплатный с ограничением по времени работы, (можно вписаться, если не сильно нагруженный) с хорошей документацией  `heroku`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого нужно использовать любой из существующих хостингов. Например [google cloud](https://cloud.google.com), если ваш бот не большой. В противном случае придется пользоваться платными хостингами.

Answer (score 0):

Я воспользовался сервисом https://www.pythonanywhere.com там все бесплатно и понятно.
Регистрируешься, затем добавляешь файлы с ботом в раздел Files и после запускаешь.